# Calculating size of chunked requests in Netty 4.1 and LittleProxy

Tags: netty, little-proxy

I'm currently running an implementation of Netty 4.1 with LittleProxy. I am modifying the code to print out the size of requests coming from the Client to Proxy, I am running into trouble when trying to calculate the size of requests with chunked transfer encoding. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction where I could calculate determine the size of each chunk as it is received and print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be code that handles `HttpContent` somewhere in LittleProxy.  You can get the length of an HTTP chunk from it:

```
HttpContent chunk = ...;
int chunkLength = chunk.content().readableBytes();
```

Comment: I ended up having to move my code to the proxyToClientResponse handling method for some reason instead of the serverToProxyResponse handling method. Thanks for the help though!